# iTerm2 where is [ ] keybindings?

Tags: macos, iterm

Is there a reason why <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> / <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> does not produce `[` and `]` in iTerm2 ?

I'm running with defaults and a `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` that produces the correct result in Terminal.app.

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using? In the US and Canadian layouts there are dedicated keys for [ and ] -- Alt-8 is • and Alt-9 is ª as per the layouts. Are you using a different layout?

Answer (score 1):

iTerm2's defaults for the Option keys are called “Esc+”, which basically means it will type an escape character (`\033`) before any character you type while holding down Option. To get the same behavior you see in Terminal, go to Preferences > Profiles > (your profile) > Keys and select Meta under both "right option key" and "left option key".